# What's the point of StructureMap's IBootstrapper interface?

Tags: structuremap

StructureMap defines an interface IBootStrapper, that I see a number of people implementing in their bootstrapper classes.

But I can't find anything that gives some indication as to why you should implement this interface.  What does one gain by doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a convention that allows tooling (like StructureMapDoctor) to discover your bootstrapping code. It is purely optional, and not required by StructureMap itself.